# Mean across each element of a tibble list-column by group with purrr and dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

I'm trying to get used to using `tidyverse`. I don't know if my data is well suited for using functions like `map()`. I like the organization of list-columns so I am wondering how to use a combination of `group_by()`, `summarize()`, `map()`, and other functions to get this to work. I know how to use these functions with vector-columns but do not know how to approach this in the case of list-columns.

Sample data:

```
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(3949)
myList <- replicate(12, sample(1:20, size = 10), simplify = FALSE)

tibble(
  group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 6),
  data = myList
)
```

Each vector in the list-column has ten elements which are values for a given trial. What I would like to do is group the tibble by `group` and then find the "column" mean and se of the expanded lists. In other words, it's like I'm treating the list columns as a matrix with each row of the tibble bound together. The output will have columns for the group and trials as well so it is in the correct format for `ggplot2`.

```
        mean        se group trial
1   6.000000 1.6329932     A     1
2  12.666667 2.3333333     A     2
3  12.333333 2.8007935     A     3
4  13.833333 1.8150605     A     4
5   8.166667 3.1028661     A     5
6  11.500000 2.9410882     A     6
7  13.666667 2.3758040     A     7
8   6.833333 1.7779514     A     8
9  11.833333 2.3009660     A     9
10  8.666667 1.7061979     A    10
11  8.333333 1.6865481     B     1
12 12.166667 2.6002137     B     2
13 10.000000 2.7080128     B     3
14 11.833333 3.1242777     B     4
15  4.666667 1.2823589     B     5
16 12.500000 3.0413813     B     6
17  6.000000 1.5055453     B     7
18  8.166667 1.6616591     B     8
19 11.000000 2.6708301     B     9
20 13.166667 0.9457507     B    10
```

Here is how I would normally do something like this:

```
set.seed(3949)

data.frame(group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 6)) %>%
  cbind(replicate(12, sample(1:20, size = 10)) %>% t()) %>%
  split(.$group) %>%
  lapply(function(x) data.frame(mean = colMeans(x[ ,2:11]),
                                se = apply(x[ ,2:11], 2, se))) %>%
  do.call(rbind,.) %>%
  mutate(group = substr(row.names(.), 1,1),
         trial = rep(1:10, 2)) %>% 

  ggplot(aes(x = trial, y = mean)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(~ group) +
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(1,10), breaks = seq(1, 10, 1)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-se, ymax = mean+se), color = "black") + 
  theme_bw()
```

Is there are cleaner way to do this with the `tidyverse` functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that another way is to use `nest()` and `map()`.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(plotrix) #For the std.error

# Your second sample dataset
set.seed(3949)
df <- data.frame(group = rep(c("A", "B"), each = 6)) %>%
  cbind(replicate(12, sample(1:20, size = 10)) %>% t()) 


df %>% 
  nest(-group) %>% 
  mutate(mean = map(data, ~rowMeans(.)), 
         se = map(data, ~ plotrix::std.error(t(.))), 
         trial = map(data, ~ seq(1, nrow(.)))) %>%
  unnest(mean, se, trial) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = trial, y = mean)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_line() +
  facet_grid(~ group) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = mean-se, ymax = mean+se), color = "black") + 
  theme_bw()
```